# Saving And Loading Entire Scenes In Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am making a game where you can build stuff while playing, im trying to figure out how to save a entire scene and load it, like with a json file or saving data of blocks placed in  a array with playerprefs. thanks

Answer (score -2):

You ideally want to place all of the data you are looking to save into a struct, then save via JSON. You can then read the JSON and then reinstate what was build previously.